# Working with WPEngine Live and Staging sites

Tags: hosting

I must be missing something because it seems like there is a major flaw in the whole staging site idea of WPEngine (and other services that provide this).

If I need to add new features/functionality to a site, I push to Staging and make my changes.  Everything goes well and I'm ready to implement those changes to the Live site. If those changes took any amount of time and they included updates that changed the database (new plugins, CPT data, etc.), how do I push to the Live site and not loose important data like new pages/posts, form submissions, comments, and most importantly, order data (if using something like WooCommerce)?

Now, I know you can do partial pushes to Live form the DB standpoint, all tables, no tables or some tables...but that seems a bit tedious, problematic or just not possible in some situations.

So how do you manage this? Is the Staging site purely for testing? Once the tests are complete, you go to the Live site and (re)implement all the changes?

Answer (score 0):

Push without the database or just push certain tables. That's what it's there for.
Or do it manually.

Staging exists for testing code and troubleshooting on an `uncached environment`.
For example if troubleshooting, you can do a full push, test things, then instead of pushing back, just replicate those changes.

The biggest issue and confusion I see is people adding posts and content there that should be added to Live, not Staging.
Rarely will you want to push all tables from Staging.

Comment: After several months using WPE, we have worked out most of the bugs.  We have pushed everything from Staging to Live just once.  As you outlined, we test on Staging and then replicate any changes on the Live install.The problem with pushing partial tables is that many plugins share the same wp_posts / wp_postmeta tables for data so you can't make large changes